# Image changing in ImageView periodically . . . 

Tags: android, ui-thread

```
package com.example.imagechange;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

ImageView imageView;
int []imageArray={R.drawable.a0,R.drawable.a1,R.drawable.a2,R.drawable.a3};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
    {
                int i=0;
                public void run() 
                {
                    imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                    i++;
                    if(i>imageArray.length-1)
                    {
                    i=0;    
                    }
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);  //for interval...
                }

    };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); //for initial delay..
  }




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
 }
```

MY ACTIVITY_MAIN :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/a0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So in the above code ,I have copied the images in the drawable and have changed it periodically but I need to get the images from the `url` and display it in the `ImageView`.

Comment: Image changing in ImageView periodically . . . . (what does this mean?) Do you want to know how bitmaps are created from URL?

Comment: no actually i want to get the images from the website . . . say i have some 4 URLs and am downloading it and showing that in the ImageView and also i have to change the images in the same imageview in regular time-interval . . . .

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageView MyImageView;
int []imageArray={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one);
    MyImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    /*here the countdown start for images*/

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
       int i=0;
       public void run() {
           MyImageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
           i++;
           if(i>imageArray.length-1) {
               i=0;    
           }
           handler.postDelayed(this, 500);  //for interval...
       }
   };
   handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000); //for initial delay..
    /*here the button click counter start */
}
```

Make first drawable folder in `re>layouts>drawable`, and place images a.png, b.png, etc. in it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sets the image from a resource in the line

> imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

What you want to do instead is use [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper) to load the image from a URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code: First you need to get the image path from URL then pass that URL to this function.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Nothing too complicated – simply create a URL object using the “src” string (i.e. String src = “http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com”), connect to it, and use Android’s BitmapFactory class to decode the input stream. The result should be your desired Bitmap object!
And after that:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply and i got it done by downloading SmartImageView - http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/